# How to compare Numpy.random's probability distribution functions

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, distribution, probability

I'd like to compare all of the probability [distributions](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/index.html) provided by `numpy.random`. Ideally I'd like to see a set of graphs comparing them but I am open to other ideas.

I can imagine going through each function and plotting using matplotlib. Perhaps someone has done it before?

Comment: "I am asking out of laziness/for everyone's future reference." kinda says it all? (hence -1)

Comment: Removed it... Didn't want to put anyone off!

Comment: Yes, but on stackoverflow, you should show that you got some basic idea of how to do it, and that you have tried, but failed (and specifically where you failed, since that is where the community tries to help you, failure in motivation cant be cured by us)

Comment: I still think it is a worthwhile question which might come up for others when searching. Time will tell I suppose.

Comment: remember to accept your own answer when it will let you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure that all of the functions are all directly comparable. However, the functions that I could compare are shown below:
[image: numpy.random pdfs]

code:

```
    loc, scale = 0., 1
    x=np.arange(-8., 8., .01)
    laplace = np.exp(-abs(x-loc/scale))/(2.*scale)
    gumbel = (1/scale)*np.exp(-(x - scale)/scale)* np.exp( -np.exp( -(x - scale) /scale) )
    logistic = np.exp((loc-x)/scale)/(scale*(1+np.exp((loc-x)/scale))**2)
    normal = 1/(scale * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi))*np.exp( - (x - loc)**2 / (2 * scale**2) )
    lognormal = (np.exp(-(np.log(x) - loc)**2 / (2 * scale**2))/ (x * scale * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)))
    rayleigh = (x/(scale*scale))*(np.exp((-x*x)/(2*scale*scale)))
    standard_cauchy = 1/(np.pi*(1+(x*x)))


    plt.plot(x,gumbel,label='gumbel scale=1')
    plt.plot(x,laplace,label='laplace scale=1, loc = 0')
    plt.plot(x,normal,label='normal scale=1, loc = 0')
    plt.plot(x,logistic,label='logistic scale=1, loc = 0')
    plt.plot(x,lognormal,label='lognormal scale=1, loc = 0')
    plt.plot(x,rayleigh,label='rayleigh scale=1')
    plt.plot(x,standard_cauchy,label='standard_cauchy')
```